# XML namespaces for OperationContext.OutgoingMessageHeaders

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have added a Service Reference to a web service I need to call. However, this webservice expects a custom header to be added to the SOAP request so that the header of the request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
   <head:Header xmlns:head="http://www.test.tt/xml/v1/Header">
      <SourceSystem/>
      <UserName>A12345</UserName>
   </head:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I tried to do that by adding a new class that looks like this:

```
public class Header
{
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Creating an instance of it:

```
var header = new Header
{
   SourceSystem = "",
   UserName = "A12345"
};
```

And then adding the header using this:

```
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Header", "http://www.test.tt/xml/v1/Header", header));
```

That gives me a header looking like this (checked in Fiddler):

```
<Header xmlns="http://www.hafslund.no/xml/v1/Header" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SourceSystem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Middleware"></SourceSystem>
  <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Middleware">A60527</UserName>
</Header>
```

Then I get authentication failed from the serving, because of the following problems:

- The precense of the `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Middleware` namespace on the `SourceSystem` and `UserName` tags.
- The `Header` tag is not prefixed with `head:`, and the xmlns is not suffixed with `:head`.

So the question is: how can I remove the namespaces from the properties of the properties of the class I send into `OutgoingMessageHeaders`, and how can I add a prefix to the header tag that get's reflected in it's xmlns property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disagree, but my answer is that your question is based on a faulty assumption. You wrongly assume that failure of authentication due to the namespace and prefix is YOUR problem. It is not your problem, it is a bug in the service your are calling. 
An endpoint that is accepting XML data should never require that you use a specific prefix with their namespace.

Comment: I totally agree that the problem lies with the service, but that service it not something I have any control over, so I have to form my request according to the service as it is now. So my question was if I could change my request to be similar to what I needed, or if I had to create the request manually. I ended up going the manual route.